# Question on diagonalizable linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Question: let $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of $2×2$ real matrices. Let $A ∈M_2(\mathbb{R})$ be of trace $2$ and determinant $-3$. Consider the linear transformation $T:M_2(\mathbb{R}) → M_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(B) = AB$.

Then my professor has written that, $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable. How they concluded this? 
Please help me.

Comment: What definition did he give of a diagonalizable endomorphism ? and of a diagonalizable matrix ?

Comment: usual definition, a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if it is similar to diagonal matrix.

Comment: Didn't know about diagonalizable endomorphism. It is just one of those random questions they solved in class.

Comment: And isn't an endomorphism $T:X\rightarrow AX$ diagonalizable iff $A$ is diagonalizable by definition ?

Comment: How by definition? I didn't get it?

Comment: $T$ is not a matrix, it is a linear application (endomorphism) . By definition : "If V is a finite-dimensional vector space, then a linear map T : V → V is called diagonalizable if there exists an ordered basis of V with respect to which T is represented by a diagonal matrix." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix

Comment: So how here, there exists order basis for $V$ such that Matrix representation of $T$ is diagonal matrix?

Comment: Hint: Matrixmultiplication $AB$ with a matrix $A$ is basically just computing $Av$ for the columns $v$ in the matrix $B$ and writing the results in a matrix. Try to use that to understand what the matrix for $T$ would look like (for a suitable matrix).

Comment: I had even found matrix representation of $T$ with respect to standard basis of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$. I saw the matrix representation is symmetric matrix and hence it is diagonalizable. But I didn't get, how to conclude this " $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: and are eigenvalues of $T$ and $A$ are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4\}$ be the canonical base of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$

$A$ is diagonalizable iff $\exists D,P\in M_2(\mathbb{R}), A=PDP^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal (in this case you can show that the diagonal terms are $\lambda_1=3$ and $\lambda_2=-1$, but that is not needed) and $P$ invertible.

Let's now consider $b=\{N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4\}=\{PM_1,PM_2,PM_3,PM_4\}$. $b$ is a base of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ because $P$ is invertible.

We have then $T(N_1)=AN_1=PDP^{-1}PM_1=PDM_1=\lambda_1N_1$ (just write $P$ and $M_1$ and do the product if you're not convinced)
Similary, $T(N_2)=\lambda_2N_2; T(N_3)=\lambda_1N_3; T(N_4)=\lambda_2N_4$

Finally, $T$ is diagonalizable, having the same eigenvalues as $A$ with twice the multiplicity.

Comment: Thank u so much.. got it.

Comment: Where we arrive at $T$ is diagonalizable? As I asked to prove $T$ is diagonalizable iff $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: In the base $b$, the matrix representing $T$ is diagonal with diagonal terms $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, both repeated twice... It is true that I formally wrote only one implication, but proving the reciprocal should be a good way of checking that you understand the concepts...

Comment: Thank u once again...